# Exlude plugin assembly from CRM Dynamics solution

Tags: dynamics-crm-4, dynamics-crm-2013

I'm trying to import a solution from a CRM 4.0 to a CRM 2013.
I having issues with the plugin assemblies. I don't really need them so I'm looking for a way to exclude or delete the plugins assemblies references from my solution.xml or customization.xml but I haven't figured it out yet.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

CRM 4.0 has no solutions (as the concept introduced with CRM 2011), if you export your customizations you can't import directly inside a CRM 2011/2013 environment, you need to upgrade the CRM instance.

You can remove the plugins using the plugin registration tool included inside the SDK (for CRM 4.0 you need to compile it first)

Answer (score 1):

1- Update your CRM4 to CRM2011 (Rollup 15 or later)

2- Update your Instance CRM2011 to 2013

3- create a new solution that contains all customization you want to import

To exclude the plugin, download the SDK and uses this tool SDK\Bin\PluginRegistration.exe

i think this is the best way